# Vertically fixed item and horizontally fixed item in the same scroll container

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I need to build a tv guide almost exactly like this one:
[tv guide](https://www2.telenet.be/content/dam/www-telenet-be/klantenservice/kijken/EPG_replay_fr.png)

- If the user scrolls horizontally in the guide, the timebar should scroll but the channel list should stay fixed.
- If the user scrolls vertically in the guide, the timebar should stay fixed but the channel list should scroll.

Is this possible with only using CSS? I'd rather not use JS to solve this because this would be laggy/glitchy.

I tried to make 2 scroll containers, 1 horizontal and 1 vertical, but I am only able to get 1 of the prerequisites right.
Here's the CodePen: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xJbEJK)

HTML:

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="horscroll">
    <div class="timebar">timeline</div>
    <div class="vertscroll">
      <div class="channel-list">channel list</div>
      <div class="content">grid</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #333;
}

.page {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.horscroll {
  width: 1000px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.timebar {
  background-color: red;
  width: 5000px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.vertscroll {
  width: 5000px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.channel-list {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 10000px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.content {
  width: 5000px;
  height: 10000px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

Can you guys help me?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Post the code you've tried.

Comment: show me your code, I will help you.

Comment: here's a CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xJbEJK